# AzureDevOps - Parameters question for YAML templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-cloudformation, devops

Alright so I have no idea if this is possible, but I was told so by someone more experienced than me...

I have a pipeline in azure devops to create a cloud formation stack. The cloudformation stack is created from a template. The template requires some parameters

Currently i am passing the parameters through hardcoding the value in the template file. This is just for testing purposes.

But I was told that there is a way to, from azure devops, prompt the customer in a GUI like way and ask them for inputs that azure devops will then place to the template?

The GUI bit...is confusing for me. Hope this is clear if anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

When creating a first level yaml pipeline the parameters works like an input source for your pipeline execution.

Just declare your parameters and it's types and use it on your pipeline tals as you need.

For example:
Creating a parameter:
[image: Defining parameter on pipeline yaml file]

Running you pipeline:
[image: Screenshot of manual running GUI]

[image: Execution log sammple]